# If a value exists in data.frame then... (R)

Tags: r, if-statement

I have two data.frame:

```
A <- c("name", "city", "code")
B <- c("code", "city")
```

I would like to see whether each value of A$city exists in B$city and in that case  to report the correspondent B$code value in a new column of A.
Here is what I've done:

```
A$code <- ""
found <- is.element(A$city, B$city)
```

Then, how should I perform the if statement?

Comment: Those are atomic vectors.

Comment: This is a merge/join operation essentially. You want to join by `city` and keep only `code` from `B`. Search here for `[r] left join`

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `%in%` operator. Here's a reprex:

```r
library('tidyverse')

A <- tribble(
  ~name, ~city, ~code,
  'foo', 'newark', '',
  'bar', 'philly', '',
  'fighter', 'sf', ''
)

B <- tribble(
  ~code, ~city,
  'X', 'philly',
  'Y', 'newark'
)

A = A %>%
  mutate(code = ifelse(city %in% B$city, B$code, NA))

A

#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>      name   city  code
#>     <chr>  <chr> <chr>
#> 1     foo newark     X
#> 2     bar philly     Y
#> 3 fighter     sf  <NA>
```

Let me know if I'm missing something. You can replace the `NA` in the `ifelse` function with `""` or whatever.

Comment: Or just `A %>% left_join(select(B,city,code), by="city")` . And you can't replace the `NA` with `NULL`, because you can't put NULL in a vector.

Comment: Good catch re: NULL, @thelatemail.

Comment: I tried the thelatemail one: it worked! Thanks a lot!